# how to dojo tabcontainer in multi dataGrid

Tags: datagrid, dojo, tabcontainer

I would like to add two tables to TabContainer.
Current state has been like this.
I made two layouts in one of TabContainer added to the structure in Datagrid but not well. Is there a way?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4Lz7.png)

Comment: When you say, "two tables"do you mean, two DataGrids? It's hard to udnerstand what the problem is on your question, If possible, try and rephrase.